# Birt Web Viewer

Tags: report, birt

I recently installed the BIRT all in one developer program and started fooling around with some reports.

Now I want to share my reports with fellow workers - What is the best way to set up a BIRT report portal?

(I Ran the Birt-viewer-demo that is on the eclipse site, but it lacks an options to view all available reports and manage them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I followed the directions at [Installing the BIRT Viewer in Tomcat](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerSetup.php) and then created pages with links to the specific reports specifying parameters using urls formed with the options specified on the page I can't link to as a new user but you can find by googling "Using the BIRT Report Viewer"

I'm not aware of any higher level tools but you may find some if you look around.

Comment: Short of installing one of the commercial platforms capable of serving reports and other web content this is the most straightforward way to handle things in a web context.  You can also choose to preview the reports in BIRT and save them in an off-line format such as PDF, Word, Excel, etc...  Those can then be shared easily via e-mail for quick review.